# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 - Creating Entity using OData API

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015, microsoft-dynamics-webapi, dynamics-crm-odata

Unsure why the following request is erroring as follows:

> Error processing request stream. The request should be a valid top-level resource object.

The request (certain details have been obfuscated for obvious reasons):

```js
POST http://someUrl.com/someUrl/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/someSet HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 387
Host: someUrl.com

{
    "paymentid": {
        "Id": "00e3f661-8d28-e321-896e-00155dfd1d05",
        "LogicalName": "payment"
    },
    "invoiceid": {
        "Id": "00e3f661-8d28-e411-896e-00155dfd1d05",
        "LogicalName": "invoice"
    },
    "AppliedAmount": 1317.53000,
    "name": "Payment Applied",
    "postingstatus": "Posted",
    "transactioncurrencyid": {
        "Id": "80870a9b-329e-d421-8a22-00155d025001",
        "LogicalName": "transactionCurrency"
    }
}
```

All logical names have been derived from running the following query:

```sql
select
    LogicalName
from 
    NHLPA_MSCRM.dbo.EntityView
where
    BaseTableName = 'paymentbase' -- | invoicebase | transactioncurrencybase
```

Comment: Recommend you to compose & test in CRM REST builder

Comment: Does navigating to `http://someUrl.com/someUrl/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/someSet` work?

Comment: There is no entity with the name `/someSet`. The url of the request must contain the logical name of an existing CRM entity. (The name is case sensitive!)

Comment: @Aron that url resolves with no issues

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen another Dutchman! I believe you've identified the issue. I will test and ping back shortly.

Answer (score 0):

> Summary: use the `OrganizationData.svc/someSet` url to get a list of the existing entities, providing perfect reference to the necessary JSON structure (minus `_metaData` properties)

So the problem ended up being quite simple.

The entity `someSet` was not the problem, as denoted by being able to access `http://someUrl.com/someUrl/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData‌​.svc/someSet` with no issues.

Drilling further into things it was the inner Logical Entity's (payment, invoice, transactioncurrency). As mentioned these logical names were derived from the database, which matched the entity settings page (image below).

[image]

However, all of the following urls would not resolve:

- `http://someUrl.com/someUrl/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData‌​.svc/paymentSet`
- `http://someUrl.com/someUrl/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData‌​.svc/invoiceSet`
- `http://someUrl.com/someUrl/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData‌​.svc/transactionCurrencySet`

The problem was that despite being **lowercase** in all places where you'd find the logical name of an entity, the first letter actually needed to be capitalized like:

- `http://someUrl.com/someUrl/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData‌​.svc/PaymentSet`
- `http://someUrl.com/someUrl/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData‌​.svc/InvoiceSet`
- `http://someUrl.com/someUrl/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData‌​.svc/TransactionCurrencySet`

And the working payload:

```
{
    "paymentid": {
        "Id": "00e3f661-8d28-e321-896e-00155dfd1d05",
        "LogicalName": "Payment"
    },
    "invoiceid": {
        "Id": "00e3f661-8d28-e411-896e-00155dfd1d05",
        "LogicalName": "Invoice"
    },
    "AppliedAmount": 1317.53000,
    "name": "Payment Applied",
    "postingstatus": "Posted",
    "TransactionCurrencyId": {
        "Id": "80870a9b-329e-d421-8a22-00155d025001",
        "LogicalName": "TransactionCurrency"
    }
}
```